# How come my background task isn't exiting right away?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios7

When I run my program, it appears that the background task runs for 20 seconds or so, no matter if the code in it is completed in a second. Here is my viewdidload:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.yesButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    self.yesButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.yesButton.layer.borderWidth= 2.0f;

    self.noButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    self.noButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.noButton.layer.borderWidth= 2.0f;

    self.invalidISBNImage.hidden = true;
    self.noInternetImage.hidden = true;
    [self.yesButton setEnabled:NO];
    [self.noButton setEnabled:NO];


    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
    {
        if([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported])
        {
            UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;

            background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                if([self canReachInternet])
                {
                    NSString *siteUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.isbnsearch.org/isbn/%@", isbnSelling];
                    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:siteUrl];
                    NSString *webDataString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];

                    if(webDataString == nil || [isbnSelling isEqualToString:@""])
                    {
                        NSLog(@"ISBN not recognized.");
                        invalidISBN = true;
                        self.invalidISBNImage.hidden = false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // This is where I parse some html
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to establish a connection to the internet.");
                    noInternetConnection = true;
                    self.noInternetImage.hidden = false;
                }

                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;


                self.titleLabel.text = title;
                self.authorLabel.text = author;
                self.editionLabel.text = edition;
                self.publisherLabel.text = publisher;
                self.datePublishedLabel.text = datePublished;
                self.bindingLabel.text = binding;

                self.loadingImage.hidden = true;

                if(!invalidISBN && !noInternetConnection)
                {
                    [self.yesButton setEnabled:YES];
                    [self.noButton setEnabled:YES];
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

For example, when the following is true: **if(webDataString == nil || [isbnSelling isEqualToString:@""])**

This line doesn't work right away: **self.invalidISBNImage.hidden = false;** when I want it to. It happens like 20 seconds later... I would think that the flow of the program would end the background task almost immediately, yet even if it gets to this part in a second, it will seem to be running the background task for up to 20 seconds still. Is there a line of code I can put to completely exit the background task?

Comment: You should dispatch statements that affect the UI on the main queue

Comment: I am not really sure how to do that. This is my first time working in background and with different queues :(

Comment: Another silly guy who doesn't know which group of APIs he is using...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731846/perfoming-ui-updates-in-secondary-queue

Comment: Thanks Paul. I see. I tried to update UI stuff in the background. Oops.